# Devise i18n resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources, internationalization, devise

I'm trying to use locale to translate devise default language (english) to portuguese. I've found a pretty good resource for that, it's working for the most part, but whenever I have a pointer to the resource variable inside the locale it gives me the name in English. For example, I have a model called User, so when something goes wrong while updating this user I would like to show a flash message containing the right translation of "User", in this case "Usuário".

Answer (score 3):

model names translations should be put to `config/locales/pt.yml`

```
pt:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Usuário
```

Comment: Is your locale set to Portuguese? What exact messages are left untranslated?

Comment: Yes, it's set correctly. Well, only the error message on the resource. The entry on the locale config is as follow:
  under errors/messages/not_saved:
    one: "Não foi possível gravar o %{resource}: 1 erro"

If I change the "resource" for "model" it says it's missing an interpolation argument.

Comment: It is not working cause Devise uses some kind of 'resource' rather than ActiveRecord object. Look at Devise::RegistrationsController.new

Answer (score 0):

Devise doesn't use ActiveRecord translations, probably not to couple with any ORM.

I've just ended up overriding devise view adding translation with ActiveRecord keys:

```
h2 =t('.sign_up')
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = display_base_errors resource
  = f.input :name, label: t('activerecord.attributes.user.name'), :autofocus => true
  = f.input :email, label: t('activerecord.attributes.user.email'), :required => true
  = f.input :password, label: t('activerecord.attributes.user.password'),:required => true
  = f.input :password_confirmation, label: t('activerecord.attributes.user.password_confirmation'), :required => true
  = f.button :submit, t('.sign_up'), :class => 'btn-primary'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

For translating other messages (not field labels) you should try https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views